# chrome extension command passing to content script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, content-script

I would like to implement a hotkey that triggers a function in my content script.
The content script (main.js) is executed on page laod from my popup.js file.

i have added the command into my manifest.json and when I add the onCommand listener to my popup.js I can console log that it gets triggered when I press my hotkey (Ctrl+Shift+K)

However I can not get it passed to my content script.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Ccghjj",
    "description": "hdjdjdjsjs",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "*storage", "activeTab"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://"],
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "js": ["jquery.js", "main.js"]
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["toolbar.html", "style.css"],
    "commands": {
        "show_deals": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K"
            },
            "description": "Highlight Deals"
        }
    }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
function registerButtonAction(tabId, button, action) {
    // clicking button will send a message to
    // content script in the same tab as the popup
    button.addEventListener('click', () => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { [action]: true }));
}

function setupButtons(tabId) {
    // add click actions to each 3 buttons
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('start-btn'), 'startSearch');
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('deals-btn'), 'startDeals');
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('stop-btn'), 'stopSearch');
}

function injectStartSearchScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        // chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'main.js' });

        // add click handlers for buttons
        setupButtons(tabs[0].id);
    });
}

injectStartSearchScript();


// hotkey command listener
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((show_deals) => {
    console.log(`Command "${show_deals}" triggered`);
    // how can I get to main.js to call deals()

});
```

**main.js (content script)**

```
async function deals() {
    // should be fired when I press my hotkey Ctrl+Shift+K
```

Comment: Your manifest shows command key of `K` and your write up refers to `D`.

Comment: sorry, corrected it - it is `K`

Comment: I'm not especially familiar with chrome extension ;so, this is more of a general suggestion.  In the command listener, you have to invoke the function based on the value of the command passed to the listener. You have only one command `show_deals` so doesn't matter unless add another.  If the listener is in the background script and the function in the content script, use your the [runtime port or one-off messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#communicating_with_background_scripts) to inform the content script to invoke it.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be much different conceptually than registering a listener in the content script itself for the `keydown` event and invoking the desired function.  You have to test which command was detected and invoke the function.  In this chrome command set up, it appears that the command listener and the function are separated, the former in the BS and the latter in the CS; but the rest of logic appears the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use messages like below

popup.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((show_deals) => {
    console.log(`Command "${show_deals}" triggered`);
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { msg: "deals"})
    })
});
```

and in your content script

```
if (!window.firstTimeExecuted) {
    window.firstTimeExecuted = true;
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((data, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (data.msg == 'deals') {
            deals()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ok we are bit futher, now it works but only if the popup windows is open. I would like to trigger deals() without having to keep the popup window open. @Ahmed Hany

Comment: got it - I have created a background.js and put the listener in it. Now it works.

Comment: running it from a background script is a good idea. Glad to help.